# Can you inject the same mobx store more than once in different components

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have never used mobx before so my understanding could be off. I have a parent component and child component both injected and observing the same store. The store is passed to props on both when components are initialized. The child component is the one triggering the store action and it accurately updates the ui with the change, however the parent component is simply referencing the same observed property from the same store and does not update or re-render when the child component updates the store. I would think that since the parent component is observing the same observed property that it should receive the updated value, but it's not.

Comment: Hey, it would be good if you add the relevant portion of your code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can inject store to any Component but you should Change mobx observable in Parent Component ,then mobx will trigger re-render and let both parent and child knows that the state has benn changed.you should use @observer on both component by the way.